# prepareForSegue EXC_BAD_ACCESS at indexPath.row

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, xcode8

I am trying to pass a data through a segue under prepareForSegue function but i keep getting exc_bad_access.

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

//NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:rowIndex inSection:0];
// Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"itemListSegue"])
{
    itemList *vc = [segue destinationViewController];
    vc.inv = [inv_list objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    vc.title = vc.inv;
}
}
```

bellow is the error i got

[image]

**EDIT:**
inv_list is declared as followed:

```
@interface downloadInv (){
NSMutableArray *inv_list;
}
```

and in viewDidLoad:

```
inv_list = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

Content:

[image]

vc.inv is a particular element in inv_list that I want to pass to the destination view controller when a table is selected.

it was declared as followed:

```
@interface itemList : UITableViewController

@property(nonatomic, strong) NSString *inv;
@end
```

[image]

Anyone know how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `inv_list` ?is it array ? make sure that you are getting correct indexpat in `prepareforsegue` and not getting nil!

Comment: Please show how `inv_list` is defined ?

Comment: Show us what the list is, and what is the property of the vc you are trying to fill.

Comment: Try declaring it as a strong property

Comment: isn't that already strong?

Comment: according to the code, inv_list is not declared as a property at all, try @property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * inv_list;

Comment: Have you printed [segue destinationViewController] NSLog the itemList whether  [segue destinationViewController] is returning as  itemList object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `in_list` is not declared as a strong property, it is probably being released.
Try declaring it like this:

`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray * inv_list;`

Answer (score 0):

Could you please check your segue identifier, If that's not given, may cause the exception

otherwise if it's made as strong property like:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *inv_list;
```

It may solve the problem.